GeoServer Unable to Access Shapefiles from External Directory in Laravel Application
I'm working on a small application designed with Laravel that makes requests to GeoServer to create workspaces and layers. Although the shapefile files for creating the layers exist and have the correct permissions, GeoServer is unable to access them.
My question is: can GeoServer access shapefiles from an external directory outside its environment? If not, where should I store these files so that GeoServer can serve them properly? Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
